# Why is this copying to the new sheet at varying intervals?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm copying data from one sheet to another 3x per week. The triggers are working fine but the data is supposed to copy to a new row sequentially. However, right now it's copying with varying numbers of rows in between them and I cant figure out why.

I have tried deleting all of the data in the sheet, deleting the sheet and recreating it, and double checked how I've input what data needs to be copied.

```
  var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data Sheet');
  var RDSheet = ss.getSheetByName('RawDataSheet');
  var lastRow = logSheet.getLastRow();
  var RawData = sourceSheet.getRange(45,1,1,34);

  RawData.copyTo(RDSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1), {contentOnly: false});
```

I expect the range (45,1,1,34), one long row, to copy itself to the `RawDataSheet` and when it triggers it places the data 1 row below the previously copied data.

Comment: `logSheet` isn't defined in your code - could you double check your code and make sure you have a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your question.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first attempt at coding anything or asking a question on here. I have defined logsheet already(updated my post). The data is copying but its not copying to the correct row or at the correct interval.

Comment: No apologies required! I can only assume it's because you're copying it to `RDSheet` but your `lastRow` is defined for `logSheet`, have you tried changing it to get the last row of `RDSheet` instead?

Comment: No I havent, how could it have been so simple?! Im trying to copy data to both sheets so would I just define it again like var lastrowdata = RDSheet.getLastRow();"


IT WORKED! Thank you Ross!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function myfunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var logSheet=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sourceSheet=ss.getSheetByName('Data Sheet');
  var RDSheet=ss.getSheetByName('RawDataSheet');
  var lastRow=logSheet.getLastRow();
  var RawData=sourceSheet.getRange(45,1,1,34);
  RawData.copyTo(logSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1), {contentOnly: false});
}
```